# How to generate HashCode in order to call Hashing#consistentHash of google/guava?

Tags: java, guava, hashcode, consistent-hashing

In [google/guava@GitHub](https://github.com/google/guava), the class [Hashing](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/e20bfcfa976182e4f435807ae0c58e7707fefa75/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.java) has implemented [consistent hashing@wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing). The method `consistentHash` requires a [`HashCode`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a9f8b899c07a33c2203b4e6cf84861646952aeed/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.java) object:

```
public static int consistentHash(HashCode hashCode, int buckets) {
  return consistentHash(hashCode.padToLong(), buckets);
}
```

I am implementing a prototype distributed key-value storage, and want to partition the keyspace by custom `Row` key and `Column` key.

```
public int locateNodeIndexFor(Row r, Column c, int buckets) {
  HashCode hashCode = // How to generate a HashCode based on @param r and @param c?
  return Hashing.consistentHash(hashCode, buckets);
}
```

Here class `Row` (and class `Column`) is simply a wrapper of a `String` field, and has its own `hashCode()` method. 
My question is how to generate a `HashCode` based on @param r and @param c in `locateNodeIndexFor` in order to call `Hashing#consistentHash`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use another `HashFunction` to hash the row and column, e.g.

```
HashCode h = Hashing.murmur3_32().newHasher()
  .putString(row.getString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  .putString(col.getString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  .hash()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow generate a hash of your row and column objects, you can do this by serializing thier data and using one of the hash-functions from the `Hashing` class, or you could use a faster hash implementation and build a `HashCode` with one of the factory methods `fromInt`, `fromLong`, `fromBytes` or `fromString`.

You could simply use your IDE to generate a Java hashCode method for your objects, then use the `HashCode.fromInt()` factory method to build the google HashCode object.
This will be much faster then serializing a string and using a cryptographic hash.
Whichever option you go with, you need to make sure that the hashcode you build will be the same when the object has the same data in it.
For example hashing the result of the `toString` method wont work, unless you are overriding the method and providing a textual representation of all your objects data. 
If you don’t override it you will just get the objects identifier which will always be different between each instance, which would default the purpose of "consistent" hashing.

Comment: You could do that, but then what's the point of doing any hashing in the first place?   `Hashing` provides plenty of fast non-crypto hash functions.

Comment: @LouisWasserman `Row` (or `Column`) has overridden `hashCode()`. Should I reuse it? Something like `HashCode.fromInt(row.hashCode())`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Can you please clarify your objection? Im not sure what you disagree with.

Comment: The Guava hashing functions will generally do a much better job of hashing without hurting performance by a significant factor.  If your keys are simple strings, you might as well.

Comment: @LouisWasserman in my tests using `goodfasthash` it was more than an order of magnitude slower than just using the string hashcode.
Adler32 was about the same and crc32 about 5 times slower.
http://pastebin.com/kDzBHNFa